# Maclaurin series expansion of an expression that involves a fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, statistical-mechanics

In the context of statistical mechanics the "classical trace" is defined as $Tr(A e^{-\beta H}) = \int dr^N dp^N  A e^{-\beta H}$ where $r^N$ and $p^N$ are phase space variables. So if $\Delta H$ is a small parameter and I wanted to linearized $Y = Tr(e^{-(H+\Delta H)}A)/Tr(e^{-(H+\Delta H)})$ I would expand $e^{-\Delta H}$ in a series order by $\Delta H$ and obtain $Y = Tr(e^{-H}(1-\Delta  H + ...)A)/Tr(e^{-H}(1-\Delta  H + ...))$. Here is where I am stuck. I know I need to multiply out the terms and collect all the terms to linear order but I do not know how to handle the fraction. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am trying to fill in the blanks of the derivation of the Fluctuation-dissipation theorem given by Chandler.

The answer Chandler arrives at is $Y(t) = Tr(e^{-H}[A(t)-(\Delta H)A(t)+A(t)Tr(e^{-H}\Delta H)/Tr(e^{-H})])/Tr(e^{-H})+O(\Delta H)^2$

Comment: If you treat the denominator as a power series $f(x)$, you can find $1/f(x)$ (again as a power series) up to any degree and then multiply to find leading terms.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @AWalker I tried to do that, but I could not get the answer given by Chandler. It is probably just because I didn't know what I was doing. Should I treat the denominator as $f(\Delta H)$? and then expand it?

Comment: The denominator I refer to is $\mathrm{Tr}(e^{-H}(1-\Delta H+\ldots)$.  Invert that and see where it gets you.

Comment: I reached the answer. I simply expanded $Y$ as a power series. So $Y(t) = Y_0(t) + Y_1(t) \Delta H + Y_2(t)(\Delta H)^2 +...$. I then multiplied both side by the denominator and equated powers of $\Delta H$ and solved Y_0(t) and Y_1(t) in turn. Thanks for the help @AWalker. I'm not sure how to close this question.